# In this attempt to show slices from a surface using javascript, why is my slider not sliding from min to max?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm tying to plot slices of a surface with a slider that selects which section of the surface you see, using the code in [slider.html](https://paste.c-net.org/CrestShawna). That code reads the surface data from [data.csv](https://paste.c-net.org/RobertaSwallow). The plot comes out fine and the slider works to move thru the surface, but only in a small range from ~80 to 100, where I want it to slide from 1-100.
I'm not too familiar with javascript and am having trouble find the error in the following script which is the guts of the slider.html file.

```
 <script>
    // Fetch the CSV file
    fetch('data.csv')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        // Parse the CSV data
        const parsedData = data
          .trim()
          .split('\n')
          .map(row => row.split(','));

        // Set up initial values for slider and selected row
        const numRows = parsedData.length - 1; // Exclude header row
        let selectedRow = 1; // Initial selected row

        // Create the initial plot with the selected row
        createPlot(selectedRow);

        // Create the slider
        const sliderElement = document.getElementById('slider');

        const sliderConfig = {
          start: [selectedRow],
          range: {
            min: 1,
            max: numRows
          },
          step: 1,
          pips: {
            mode: 'count',
            values: 5
          }
        };

        noUiSlider.create(sliderElement, sliderConfig);

        sliderElement.noUiSlider.on('update', (values) => {
          selectedRow = Math.floor(values[0]); // Round to nearest integer
          createPlot(selectedRow);
        });

        // Function to create the plot with the selected row
        function createPlot(row) {
          const x = parsedData[0].slice(1);
          const y = parsedData[row].slice(1);

          const data = [{
            x: x,
            y: y,
            type: 'scatter',
            mode: 'lines'
          }];

          const layout = {
            title: '2D Curve from Surface Data',
            xaxis: { title: 'X' },
            yaxis: { title: 'Y' }
          };

          Plotly.newPlot('chart', data, layout);
        }
      });
  </script>
```